# What is the ideal damping ratio for a building?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I am a high school student investigating how the mass ratio of a pendulum tuned mass damper inside a building (ratio of the mass of the pendulum tuned mass damper to the mass of the structure) affects the damping ratio when the building vibrates. How do I select the ideal mass ratio for a structure based on the damping ratios I've gotten? In other words, what value of the damping ratio is ideal with regards to the safety/comfort for the citizens inside the structure?

Answer (score 3):

The optimum damping ratio is that which produces a *critically damped* system. Critical damping dissipates the system energy in the shortest possible time and does not support oscillation. For a critically damped system, the damping ratio is equal to 1.